# Meaning of a canonical transformation "preserving" a differential form?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism

In Chapter 9 of Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics*, we find the following definition:

> Let $g$ be a differentiable mapping of the phase space $\mathbb R^{2n}$ to $\mathbb R^{2n}$. The mapping $g$ is called *canonical* if $g$ preserves the $2$-form $\omega^2 = \sum dp_i \wedge dq_i$.

My question is, what does it mean to preserve a differential form? If we write the mapping as $g : (p, q) \mapsto (P, Q)$, does it mean that $\sum dP_i \wedge dQ_i = \sum dp_i \wedge dq_i$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

It's a narrow class of possible variable changes.

Comment: Thanks. So for $n=1$, we would need $\frac{\partial P}{\partial p} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial q} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial q} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial p} = 1$?